# using 32bit dll in a 64bit applications in same application pool

Tags: iis, 32bit-64bit, application-pool

I have a 64bit application running under IIS. It connects to SQL server using a 64bit DSN however I want to use a 32bit dll as an external library.

When I enable 32bit applications in Applicatio Pool settings, I get the error of `architecture mismatch` for DSN and if I disable it, the dll no more works with the error `ActiveX component can't create object`.

How should I use this 32bit dll in a 64bit application pool?

Comment: You can't run 32 and 64 bit DLL's in the same process (in this case the IIS worker process). I suggest you wrap the simpler one inside a webservice and call the webservice from the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simular setup; a 64bit web application using a 32bit dll. The only difference I see is that I don't use a DSN to connect to my SQL server, but instead use a connectionstring as below.

```
data source=YOURSERVER;initial catalog=YOURDATABASE;Persist Security Info=False;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Can you change your connectionstring?

**Edit:**

If you must use a DSN, check that a 32bit version of it exists via the 32bit ODBC administrator at %windir%\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe.

Comment: have you enabled 32bit applications on it?

Comment: Yes, in the same way as you explained.

Comment: If you've enabled 32bit then this isn't a 64 bit web application. You can only run one or the other.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You are right, it is more correct that I say it is a web application on a 64bit windows machine.